# Nonlinear Transformation of a Vector Space.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Consider a set $\mathcal{X}$. Consider a function $\phi:\mathcal{X} \to \mathbb{R}^d$.
Suppose that $S_1 \equiv \{\phi(x) | x \in \mathcal{X}\}$ is a $d$-dimensional vector space (i.e., there is a set of $x_1, x_2, \dots x_d$ such that $\forall_{i\neq j} \phi(x_i)$ is linearly independent from $\phi(x_j)$). Consider a non-linear mapping $f:\mathcal{X}\to\mathcal{X}$. Consider

$$
S_2 \equiv \{\phi(x) - \gamma \phi(f(x)) | x \in \mathcal{X}\}
$$

Furthermore. Consider a distribution $p$ over $\mathcal{X}$. Is there any specific requirement that is sufficient to ensure that

$$
\mathbb{E}_{x\sim p}\left[\phi(x)\phi^\intercal(x)\right]
$$

is invertible
(notice that inside the expectation there is an outerproduct). Is it enough that $p$ is positive everywhere (i.e., $p(x) > 0$ $\forall x \in \mathcal{X}$)?
Under which condition of $f$, $S_1$ and $S_2$ have at least one $d$-dimensional basis in common?

Comment: Ensure what? Your question is incomplete.

Comment: Hi @WillM. Thanks for pointing that out. I corrected my question(s). In short I would like to know what is the simplest condition to ensure that $\mathbb{E}_{x \sim p}[\phi(x)\phi^\intercal(x)]$ is invertible, and also to understand for which $f$ it is guaranteed that $\mathcal{S}_1$ and $\mathcal{S}_2$ share a $d$-dimensional basis (i.e., a set of linearly independent vectors that belong both the sets)